# Does anyone know how can I validate digits from my currency input?

Tags: swift, xcode

My validation rules :
only accepts 5 numbers, only accepts 2 decimals
I have this so far but the problem is that stil accepts more than 2 decimals for example:
$ 99,999.00123445 (not Ok)
$ 99,999.99 (Ok)
I set numbers left to right for example: $0.01, $0.19, $1.99
What is wrong?

```
@IBAction func efectivoTextChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    guard let text = sender.text else{
        return
    }
    let array = text.compactMap({
        Int(String($0))
    })
    let num = Double(array.reduce(0, {($0 * 10) + $1})) / 100
    if num > 99999.99 {
        return
    }
    let num2 = num * 100 / 100
    efectivoTextField.text = currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:  num2))
    let updatedText = efectivoTextField.text!
    updateEfect(updatedText)
}
```

Comment: IDK who the target demographic of your program is, but just so you know, most people in the world don't write currencies that way.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a `Double` to compute currency. `Double`s are base-2 (binary), so "two decimal places" doesn't apply. A `Double` cannot express `1/10` precisely any more than you can express `1/3` precisely in base-10 (decimal).

If you want to work in base-10, as you need to for currency, then you either need to use a `Decimal` or an `Int`. With an `Int`, you would work in `cents`, and then format the value at the end.